# How to disable publish button if post title exists

Tags: title

Happy New Year 2017

I'm a newbie of both PHP and WordPress, so I have a question want to ask.

Like the title, how can I disable Publish button if post title exists.

Many thanks to everybody

P/S: I have used **Duplicate Title Checker** Plugin checks for existing post title.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you could always do with the help of jQuery Ajax, and [`get_page_by_title('About', OBJECT, 'post')`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) tool.

You basically listen to changes on the title field, check if at least 1 post already exists with same title, then enable the submit button if it doesn't, otherwise keep it disabled as it is by default (on page load, the button gets disabled until further check).

```
add_action('wp_ajax_check-posts-by-title', function(){
    $title = isset( $_REQUEST['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $_REQUEST['title'] ) : null;
    // check for title
    if ( !$title ) {
        return wp_send_json(array(
            'enable_btn' => false,
            'message' => 'No title specified!' 
        ));
    }
    $post = get_page_by_title($title, OBJECT, 'post');
    // check for post
    if ( isset($post->ID) && 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
        return wp_send_json(array(
            'enable_btn' => false
        ));
    }
    // nothing caught
    return wp_send_json(array(
        'enable_btn' => true
    ));
    // kill response
    wp_die();
});

add_action('admin_footer', function() { 
    global $pagenow;

    if ( !$pagenow || !in_array($pagenow, array( 'post-new.php' )) )
        return; // only enqueue when writing/editing posts
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $(document).on("change", "#titlediv #title", function(e){
                var i = $(this)
                  , f = i.closest('form')
                  , t = i.val()
                  , b = $('input[name="publish"]', f).first();

                if ( self.xhr ) {
                    self.xhr.abort();
                } else {
                    var xhr;
                }

                if ( !b.length ) return;
                b.attr('disabled','disabled');

                if ( $.trim( t ) ) {
                    self.xhr = $.ajax({type: 'post', url: 'admin-ajax.php', data: {
                        action: 'check-posts-by-title',
                        title: t
                    }, success: function(res){
                        if ( res && res.enable_btn ) {
                            b.removeAttr('disabled');
                        } else {
                            if ( res.message ) {
                                alert(res.message);
                            }
                        }
                    }, error: function(){
                        i.trigger('change'); // roll over
                    }});
                }
            });
            $('#titlediv #title').trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

Hope that helps.